# Why am I not getting the AJAX data in an ASP.Net MVC controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code on my page:

```js
polyData = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4];
document.getElementById('sentDiv').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(polyData);

$.post('/Home/updateData', $.param({
  data: JSON.stringify(polyData)
}, true), function(data) {
  $("#dataDiv").html("this is data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

This is in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult updateData(List<double> polyData)
{
  return Json(polyData);
}
```

When I made the AJAX call my `updateData` in the controller is called, but `polydata` is `null` and no data is passed to it via the AJAX call. I can see on the web page (sentData div) that `polyData` has valid values. Why is data not passed correctly?

How can I see what is the JSON message that received by controller and how controller tried to extract them to polyData and debug the process?

Comment: Change `data:` to `polyData:`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Really? I would have thought it should be `data: polyData`?

Comment: You may need to add `[FromBody]`, as in `public JsonResult updateData([FromBody] List<double> polyData)`

Comment: @DavidG that was my next line of inquiry :) Although the data not being received is because the OP is sending the argument named `data`, yet the action is expecting `polyData`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It helped. Please make it an answer and I will accept it. I changed the name of variable in controller to data and now it is filled.

Comment: @mans glad to help. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the action in your controller is expecting a parameter named `polyData`, yet your AJAX request is sending `data`. You simply need to change the name of the value you send:

```
$.param({
  polyData: JSON.stringify(polyData)
}, true)
```

Also note that you may also note need the `$.param` or the `JSON.stringify` calls, but this depends on how your model and model binder is structured.

Comment: it is not answer sir

Comment: Read the comments above. I commented this and the OP stated it fixed the issue and asked me to post it as an answer.